# Match column names to get corresponding other values inside lapply function

Tags: r, match, lapply, sapply

I have a Base dataframe consisting of the following columns:

```
Base <- data.frame(Currency = c("EUR.", "EUR.", "USD.", "USD.", "GBP."), Quantity = c(393858,597184,673522,110204,38051625), Price_local = c(168,119.2,168.29,1221.14,1.45), FX_rate = c(1.0898, 1.0898, 1, 1, 1.2287), Exposure.USD = c(72110043,77576686,113347017,134574513,67723215))
```

I have another dataframe by the name FX_Stress consisting of following columns:

```
FX_Stress <- data.frame(V1 = c("FXDown5", FXDown10", "FXUp5", "FXUp10"), V2 = c(0.95,0.90,1.05,1.10))
```

What I want is to add new columns to Base data frame having the column names of the first column of FX_Stress data frame i.e. FXDown5, FXDown10, FXUp5 and FXUp10. Also I want these new columns to be filled by a specific formula. For ex- For new column Base$FXDown5 the formula would be:

```
Base$FXDown5 <- ifelse(Base$Currency == "USD.", 0, ((1/((1/Base$FX_rate)*0.95))*(Base$Price_local)*Base$Quantity)-Base$Exposure.USD)
```

The 0.95 used in the above formula is obtained from the column V2 in FX_Stress corresponding to FXDown5 in column V1. This is working like this and the correct values under new column Base$FXDown5 are coming as 3795265.77, 4082983.35, 0, 0, 3638201.71. But I have to fill lot of columns and I cannot write a new formula for each new column. Therefore I tried to use lapply function to fill all the new columns at once. These are mentioned below:

```
Base[FX_Stress[,1]] <- 0
Base[FX_Stress[,1]] <- lapply(Base[FX_Stress[,1]], function(x) {ifelse(Base$Currency == "USD.", 0, ((1/((1/Base$FX_rate)* FX_Stress$V2[match(names(x), FX_Stress$V1)]))*(Base$Price_local)*Base$Quantity)-Base$Exposure.USD)})
```

But in the output I am getting NA values for the currencies which are not USD. (for USD. currency its coming as 0 which is correct). If I do individually for each column its coming correctly but when I use lapply to match column names NA values are coming for currencies which are not USD. Could anyone help regarding the lapply formula which I have used to get the correct values for the new columns at once. This can be done through using dplyr and functions like gather and spread but I would request help regarding how it can be done using lapply/sapply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `sapply()` in this way

```
Base <- cbind(Base,`colnames<-`(sapply(FX_Stress$V2, function(x) with(Base,ifelse(Currency == "USD.", 0, FX_rate/x * Price_local * Quantity - Exposure.USD))),FX_Stress$V1))
```

such that

```
> Base
  Currency Quantity Price_local FX_rate Exposure.USD FXDown5 FXDown10    FXUp5   FXUp10
1     EUR.   393858      168.00  1.0898     72110043 3795266  8012227 -3433811 -6555458
2     EUR.   597184      119.20  1.0898     77576686 4082983  8619632 -3694128 -7052426
3     USD.   673522      168.29  1.0000    113347017       0        0        0        0
4     USD.   110204     1221.14  1.0000    134574513       0        0        0        0
5     GBP. 38051625        1.45  1.2287     67723215 3638202  7602725 -3158124 -6092901
```

**DATA**

```
Base <- data.frame(Currency = c("EUR.", "EUR.", "USD.", "USD.", "GBP."), Quantity = c(393858,597184,673522,110204,38051625), Price_local = c(168,119.2,168.29,1221.14,1.45), FX_rate = c(1.0898, 1.0898, 1, 1, 1.2287), Exposure.USD = c(72110043,77576686,113347017,134574513,67723215))

FX_Stress <- data.frame(V1 = c("FXDown5", "FXDown10", "FXUp5", "FXUp10"), V2 = c(0.95,0.90,1.05,1.10))
```

**with OP's original formula**

```
Base <- data.frame(Currency = c("EUR.", "EUR.", "USD.", "USD.", "GBP."), Quantity = c(393858,597184,673522,110204,38051625), Price_local = c(168,119.2,168.29,1221.14,1.45), FX_rate = c(1.0898, 1.0898, 1, 1, 1.2287), Exposure.USD = c(72110043,77576686,113347017,134574513,67723215))

FX_Stress <- data.frame(V1 = c("FXDown5", "FXDown10", "FXUp5", "FXUp10"), V2 = c(0.95,0.90,1.05,1.10))

Base <- cbind(Base,`colnames<-`(sapply(FX_Stress$V2, function(x) ifelse(Base$Currency == "USD.", 0, ((1/((1/Base$FX_rate)*0.95))*(Base$Price_local)*Base$Quantity)-Base$Exposure.USD)),FX_Stress$V1))
```

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out that the formula is more complicated than it needs to be. `((1/((1/Base$FX_rate)*x))*(Base$Price_local)*Base$Quantity)-Base$Exposure.USD))` simplifies to `Base$FX_rate/x * Base$Price_local * Base$Quantity - Base$Exposure.USD`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I am still getting NA values for non USD. currencies when I am using your formula. Not sure whats the issue

Comment: @ss003 Did you clean up your global environment before running the code? For me it works well. Maybe you can use my code along with the data in my answer to try it

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Its working.. Great thanks to you...Can you please explain a bit more in detail how you applied sapply function so that I can do the same for similar situations...And can the formula provided by me not modified in which lapply and match functions were used. If so could you point out the error in my formula if possible.

Comment: @ss003 in the `sapply()` function, I only used the column `V2` for the parameters that will be passed to the your formula...Note that `V2` contains 4 values, so `sapply()` will pass all 4 values to your formula, yielding a matrix with 4 columns

Comment: @ss003 yes, you can use your function, but you should use the same field names in your formula as in data frames `Base`, otherwise the interpreter will treat it as `NA` since it is not defined or declared yet...

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I edited my post mentioning the correct field names but I get NA values for non USD. currencies. I dont know where the error is

Comment: @ss003 it should be `FX_rate` in your formula, rather than `FX_Rate`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Again I changed to FX_rate but I was talking of the lapply formula in which it was already FX_rate and still the output came as NA for non USD. currencies

Comment: @ss003 I added the code that with your original formula, you can try the code, which works fine in my computer....

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks...Your code is working great